# Getting to jQuery plugins to "see" jQuery in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

In my `main.ts` file I have jQuery imported and the plugin required like so:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import * as $ from 'jquery';
require('./vendors/tablesaw');
```

This works as expected, everything is bundled correctly (using webpack), but the plugin throws a `$ is not defined` error, so the question is how do I get it to "see" jQuery as it's been imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I managed to figure out a workaround. You can expose jQuery globally in webpack projects, so putting the following into the webpack `config` object:

```
resolve: {
     alias: {
            jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, 'jquery.min.js')
     }
}
```

And putting this into your webpack entry file:

```
require('expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery');
```

And finally install expose-loader:

```
npm install expose-loader --save
```

Will do the trick, making jQuery visible to all plugins etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) jQuery to the `window` object to make it globally available, similar to how it would load on its own:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
Object.assign(window, { $ });
```

---

When I tried to expose jQuery to the global scope from my TypeScript entry file like so:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
window.$ = $;
```

I got the error `Property '$' does not exist on type 'Window'`, but the method above seems to compile and work without issues.